# How to make a not .NET Assembly

Tags: .net

As I have knew that all .NET Assemblies can be decompiled ( view its source code ) and I know that there's obfuscator to protect the source but also its can be de-obfuscated so I wanted to make a tool that's not a .NET Assembly ?

Comment: So what you're asking for is a way to convert a .NET assembly into native, under the premise that a native assembly hides your source?

Comment: Simple write code which is not compiled to IL. for instance in native c++

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Mono to perform an ahead of time compilation](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT). But in the general case this is not possible because you can not really know for what types you have to instantiate generic types. Mono tries to figure it out using static analysis techniques but if you instantiate generic types using reflection this will obviously fail.